# Unable to run telnet commands on Genymotion emulator on Mac

Tags: android, macos, osx-yosemite, genymotion

I am running Genymotion 2.3.1 on Mac OS X Yosemite. When I was running Genymotion on Win 7, I could telnet to the emulator and run commands like "geo fix" to set a location. However, on Yosemite, when I telnet to the emulator and run a command, I do not get an OK response, and nothing happens. This is an example:

```
$ adb devices
List of devices attached
192.168.56.101:5555 device

$ telnet 192.168.56.101 5555
Trying 192.168.56.101...
Connected to 192.168.56.101.
Escape character is '^]'.
geo fix 34 -118
sms send 1234 test
Connection closed by foreign host.
$
```

After running the `geo fix` command, I checked on the emulator, and the GPS location was not changed. The `sms send` command caused the telnet session to close. Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Telnet is not supported on Genymotion.

To access the Genymotion Shell you need to open the Genyshell app or  run it in command line. It will open a terminal where you will be able to do all the commands you used to do.

The commands are different than telnet, so type `help` to discover all the features you can access after opening this shell.