# Using telnet localhost with genymotion's Android emulator

Tags: android, localhost, emulation, telnet, genymotion

Im taking a Coursera course on Android programming and we have to alter the wifi signal.  He connects to telnet using

```
 telnet localhost 5554
```

on his emulator.  I find the emulator that he uses to be too slow for me so I am using Genymotion for my emulator.  However, the telnet localhost 5554 command doesnt work for me.  Ive also tried using telnet localhost [my IPv4 address]
and that doesnt work either.

Any ideas?

Comment: Hope this answer will help you!

Visit http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28936822/unable-to-run-telnet-commands-on-genymotion-emulator-on-mac

Comment: duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28936822/unable-to-run-telnet-commands-on-genymotion-emulator-on-mac
Apparently you can't. You have to use genymotion shell

Answer (score 0):

You should use genymotion shell app to communicate with genymotion virtual machine. After running the shell type help to list all available commands.